# Are there database testing tools for python (like sqlunit)?

Tags: python, database, testing, sqlalchemy

Are there database testing tools for python (like sqlunit)? I want to test the DAL that is built using sqlalchemy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the design pattern that Django uses.

1. Create a disposable copy of the database.  Use SQLite3 in-memory, for example.
2. Create the database using the SQLAlchemy table and index definitions.  This should be a fairly trivial exercise.
3. Load the test data fixture into the database.
4. Run your unit test case in a database with a known, defined state.
5. Dispose of the database.

If you use SQLite3 in-memory, this procedure can be reasonably fast.